# WSO2BPS denies deployment of a new version of process to a prod environment

Tags: deployment, wso2, versioning, production-environment, wso2-business-process

WSO2 BPS denies deploying new version CAR-file due to "Service already used by another process. Try again with a different service name".

The issue is known, but I havent found any valuable key to solve the problem.

Obviously, we should keep in mind two things:

1. We cant change service name because it forces the change of endpoint URL (its noncence to change URL on every node that uses BPS services).
2. We should keep the existing processes on the previous version to end up. So we cant just delete the old version and deploy the new one (not saying that will produce "gap" when no service is deployed at all).

The documentation for previous BPS versions says that in that case process service definition is changed for the new version of process. Now thats not true, because

- New service definition is denied to upload.
- New process package is not uploaded at all after above described error.

So what should we do to handle this? I think this problem just makes usage of BPS impossible in prod environments, so there should defenitelly be a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully solve this problem I stopped using CARs and started using only zips instead. They deploy all required artifacts and dont redeploy the way like they want on startup. Old instances continue living in the retired processes, new come to active ones. Everyone is happy!